# Boolean indexing to find character

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas DataFrame called 'line' that is either a string representation of a number, or a string representation of two numbers separated by the '&' symbol. So I want to find the index points of all the observations that have '&' in the 'line' column.

I know I can do this:

```
index_points = []
for row in df.index:
    if '&' in df.loc[row, 'line']:
        index_points.append(row)
```

But i don't like it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.str` to perform vectorized string operations on the column:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({"line": ["1", "2&3", "4", "5&6", "7&8"]})
>>> df.line.str.contains("&")
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: line, dtype: bool
```

And then you can use this to index into the index or the frame, as you like:

```
>>> df.index[df.line.str.contains("&")]
Int64Index([1, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
>>> df[df.line.str.contains("&")]
  line
1  2&3
3  5&6
4  7&8
```

Comment: god I love the vectorised operations in pandas. Thanks!